# General Function Failure while trying to publish a map package from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, general-function-failure

I had a general function failure error message while trying to publish a map package from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple reasons to trigger this behavior.

Now, to proceed try below:

1. Close the application and,
2. Navigate to `C:\Users\Administrator(user)\AppData\Local` and rename the ESRI folder
3. Navigate to `C:\Users\Administrator(user)\AppData\Roaming` and rename the ESRI folder

Try republishing the package.

If the above does not work, you can directly host the map package as an item through the contents page:

[image]